# Использование bootstrap для сайтов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, функции

Всем привет!

У меня не проблема, а чисто пояснительный вопрос.

Есть сайт (собственных исходников где-то на полтора мегабайта), каркас делал сам, оформление делал сам, наполнение делал сам, часть функционала делал сам, часть - использовал внешние библиотеки, например, для календаря использовал datepicker из jquery-ui (только с полностью переопределённым css под мои нужды), когда не хватало немного функционала внешних библиотек, то разбирал их (если было нужно) и дописывал. Свои эффекты (пусть и с некоторыми внешними библиотеками), свой псевдотеговый язык (правда ооооооооочень маленький) для автоматического быстрого формирования страниц (с графиками и отчетами - пользователю системы надо просто указать какими параметрами он хочет управлять и как, сайт автоматически выстроит форму для запроса, автоматически будет собирать и обрабатывать данные, формировать запросы для сервера, получать и выводить запросы с сервера и т.д.)

И встал такой вопрос - а надо ли мне смотреть в сторону библиотеки bootstrap, может ли он мне дать хоть что-то положительное в такой ситуации? Уменьшит код, ускорит сайт, сделает проще отладку и наращивание функционала и т.д.

Это был первый вопрос.

А вот и второй:

Надо создать более простой сайт, в принципе можно делать с нуля, могу взять свой за основу, все вырезать, сохранив каркас и нужный для данного сайта функционал или все таки создать с нуля, но используя современные всеми используемые фреймворки?

Ну и в качестве бонуса - третий вопрос

Вам надо создать функционал (css преобразование элемента, работа с DOM и т.д. конкретного элемента).

Что предпочтительнее - сделать вызов через jQuery

```
$(my_element).my_functional(params);
```

или все таки как вызов некоторой независимой функции

```
my_functional($(my_element), params);
my_functional(my_element, params);
```

Comment: вы прочитайте что такое бутстрап и сами решение примите, нужен он вам в вашем проекте или нет. Никто вам на этот вопрос не ответит.

Comment: @teran, в том то и дело, что прочитал, посмотрел примеры, посмотрел как много народу его используют, поэтому и встал такой вопрос. Пока единственной причиной его использовать для меня - чтобы не было больших проблем с разработкой мобильной и десктопной версий. Но у меня постоянно ощущение, что я микроскопом забиваю гвозди.

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует отталкиваться от имеющихся задач.

Основное преимущество `Bootstrap` - `адаптивность` и `кроссбраузерность`. Так же его используют для повышения скорости разработки веб-сайта. Если у вас есть готовый сайт с необходимым функционалом, который хорошо отображается на всех устройствах - особого смысла использования `Bootstrap` нет.

Если адаптация необходима - `Bootstrap` будет весьма полезен. Скорости работе сайта он не добавит, т.к. он весьма громоздкий с многочисленными строками кода.

Дизайн сайта, так же с использованием данного фреймворка, будет иметь свои особенности. И не под каждый дизайн он подойдет. Разумеется, работая с данным фреймворком очень хорошо `кастомизировать` его под свои цели, чтобы сайт был более индивидуальным.